# Another CSS overlapping issue

Tags: css, html, overlap, centering

UPDATE: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5PRt/5/).

I want it to look like this:

[image: What I want it to look like]

... but it looks like this:

[image: What I don't want it to look like]

The #container is horizontally centered, and must stay so. Can't seem to get this right...

Comment: Can you link to the page or post the CSS in a fiddle? Also, for now, try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#container`

Comment: Could be that the widths of the section and footer img are larger than the container.  Including padding, margin, and borders.  Post some code so it is clearer.  Maybe recreate it in JSFiddle.net and post a link here.

Comment: Maybe apply a negative top margin to the footer image or `position: relative; top: -xxxpx`.

Comment: Please either link or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Question updated with a jsFiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bryan Downing in the comments gave me a clue.

I added

```
footer #container {
    position: relative;
    top: -XXXpx;
}
```

Works perfect. Big thanks to you wizards :)

This should be useful for others. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5PRt/7/) with answer. Code below:

```
header, #container, section, footer, footer img#iphone { display: block; }


header {
    background: url('images/header.jpg') repeat-x;
    height: 160px;

    border: 5px solid #aa3;
    color: #aa3;
}
    header img#logo {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

#container {
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    overflow: hidden;

    border: 5px solid #33a;
    color: #33a;
}

section {
    float: left;    
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;

    border: 5px solid #3a3;
    color: #3a3;
}

footer {
    background: url('images/footer.jpg') repeat-x;
    height: 150px;

    border: 5px solid #aa3;
    color: #aa3;
}
    footer #container {
        position: relative;
        top: -320px;
    }
    footer img#iphone {
        float: right;    
        height: 400px;
        width: 204px;

        border: 5px solid #a33;
        color: #a33;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you float boxes side by side, one box to the left, the other to the right, both having `width:50%`. But padding, margins and border unintentionally increase the width of the boxes causing them to be more than 50% and forcing the right box to move under the previous box.

try setting static width to the boxes (will need calculation)

http://jsfiddle.net/fuYYv/

Comment: Good explanation of the CSS box model, @fskreuz. Here's an in-depth look at it: http://css-tricks.com/2841-the-css-box-model/

Comment: Not exactly my case, but good info none the less. Answer posted below.